# How to set Website Owner

Tags: administration

I've helped my school making its website, but a friend of mine who made it with me, somehow set himself as the 'owner' so whenever I link the website the Google Preview lists an image and a written saying 'by ...' how do I find that name and replace it?

I want to replace it with my teacher's, thanks.

Comment: Isn't it easier to ask your friend what he did?

Comment: He's not so Smart on these things.. He probably neither will remember what he did..

Comment: Is there any Meta data I can edit somewhere? Don't know

Comment: Start by looking at the source code of your website (Ctrl-U or F12), and search for the text you mention.

Comment: Please provide a link to the website.

Comment: http://liceocroceroma.it

Answer (score 1):

To change the author name globally, go to your administrator page, open **Users -> User Manager** then find your friend's name using the search field. Simply change it to your teacher name, if you found it.

To change the author name indiviually, manually, go to **Content -> Manage**. Find the article you want to change, then in the **Publishing** tab, enter your teacher name in the **Author** field.

Please note that any changes you made, will take some time for Google to fix it, at least until they re-crawl your pages.

Comment: Oh, well, the problem persists, because when I share the Website itself, not an article, it always displays that name

Comment: I mean, in the homepage there are 2 articles made by me, but the name is always of the other guy, not the teacher's @webchun

Comment: what is the name of this guy and how did you share the page?

Comment: Its Riccardo and I simply scared it ad a link in FB

Comment: There is no 'Ricardo' name/word on your home page and when I share it on facebook there is no such name also. http://i.imgur.com/kM17271.png

Comment: You sure you put double C? RiCCardo

Comment: yap, I'm sure https://www.dropbox.com/s/hssfvhwo8mf869v/hfuvp.mp4?raw=1

Comment: btw, it's probably your browser. Try to clear all of your browser caches and try to share your website again on facebook

Comment: I think that might be the problem yeah, I'll let you know but now I had to turn it off, so enjoy your day, I'll let you know that probably this evening (morning for me)

Comment: Yes it worked like a charm ;)

Comment: Ehm... it worked somewhere else but not on Facebook >.< @webchun (Sorry about that)